# How is RNJR a color

Tags: rwby

When Ren and Nora are arguing about what their new team name should be Nora wants it to be JNRR (Junior) but Ren's like but that's not a color so how is RNJR (ranger) any better?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to the [RNJR](http://rwby.wikia.com/wiki/RNJR) team wiki, Ren says the team name should be RNJR because Ranger is actually a shade of green

> As per the [Color Naming Rule](http://rwby.wikia.com/wiki/Color_Naming_Rule), the color that RNJR brings up is a shade of green called ranger green.